# Json deserializer quicktype

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'am trying to deserialize parts of Json that is in my file. I'm using xy.json file in my project.

```json
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "letter":"A",
    "ordered_teams":[{
      "id":1,
      "country":"France",
      "alternate_name":null,
      "fifa_code":"FRA",
      "group_id":1,
      "group_letter":"A",
      "wins":4,
      "draws":0,
      "losses":1,
      "games_played":5,
      "points":12,
      "goals_for":10,
      "goals_against":4,
      "goal_differential":6
    }]
  }
]
```

I have 2 classes generated by quicktype

this is my `Data` class

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
public long Id { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("letter")]
public string Letter { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("ordered_teams")]
public List<Team> OrderedTeams { get; set; }
```

I am trying to get the List of orderedTeams:

```
data podatci = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<data>(json)
```

and return `data.OrderedTeams`;

But I'm getting null reference.

Don't know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

Your json seems to contain an array at start, try with

```cs
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<data>>(json)
```